# What is the grammatical structure of the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

I would like to know the grammatical structure of the sentence below:

> The next morning she wrote her son, David, asking for important information.

I am confused as it is not in a suitable structure like relative clause (connection with which/ who).

Could you please explain how we could connect the second sentence with "asking".

Comment: It's a non-finite clause. A non - finite clause is a subordinate clause that contains a participle or an infinitive and hasn't got a subject. It can start with a subordinating conjunction. But there are also non-finite clauses, which do not begin with a subordinating conjunction.

Comment: ...and then there are those that do have a subject, if the subject isn't the same as in the main clause.

Comment: Can you tell us the source of the quoted sentence, please/

Comment: Thanks for your supports. Sentence was a part from the novel "4:50 from Paddington".